# inserting data in database through thread

Tags: python, database, multithreading, sqlite

Hi I have client server architecture. 
1. server script:
     -runs and listen to socket.
     -on receiving client response, a new thread is forked to handle the client data
     -each thread has to accept the data send by client and store to database
2. Client script:
- runs with timer of every 0.02 second and sends data to server through socket

Now When I run the both script, database get locked frequently.

please let me know how should I handle this. 
If you required to see script then let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Your question tags indicate that you are using SQLite. The SQLite database is not really designed for concurrent operation on the same database, its locks are [per-database-file](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html). This means that your threads are not running in parallel, but waiting for an exclusive lock on the entire database, which effectively serializes them.

If you need concurrent writes, you should switch to a client-server database that offers finer-grained locking of writes, such as PostgreSQL.

Comment: Just thought, implementing queue on server side and doing bulk insert. Do you think that you will be applicable for client-server architecture

Comment: @dilip Inserting in a batch is likely to speed things up — provided your database changes are pure insertions. If you must also update, delete, and read from the database, batching will not solve the problem. Databases like PostgreSQL or Oracle are capable of locking only the part of the table that you're working on, so multiple clients can read and write simultaneously.

Comment: yes, I need insertions only.But the main problem is connection. I have to connect/open database from each thread because sharing connection between thread will not allowed in python(not sure).Since I can't switch database, need help on managing things within sqlite with thread safety.

Comment: @dilip I don't see why you wouldn't be allowed to share a connection between threads, as long as you lock the operations.